# angular state.go navigation between two modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two separate modules and am trying to use $state.go() to navigate between them, but without success at the moment.

Some truncated code:

```
var mod1 = angular.module('mod1',['ui-router', etc.]);
mod1.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) 
{
$stateProvider.state('state1', {etc.})
}
```

Second module:

```
var mod2 = angular.module('mod2',['ui-router', 'mod1', etc.]); //inject mod1

mod2.controller('ctl2',['$state', function($state)
    {
      $scope.navigate = function()
      {
       alert('got here'); //test
       $state.go('state1');
      }
    }]);
```

That's the basic outline, anyway. The alert triggers, so I know I'm making into the navigate() function, but the page doesn't navigate over to 'state1' and its defined URL/template. It also doesn't throw any errors, so I don't even really know where to begin to debug.

Comment: Can you show us the state declarations?

Comment: It was an issue with parameters. Lesson learned: always, always, always make sure the expected state parameters are actually being sent with real values.